Resolving remote adress from local network not working
I have a local network with a proxmox server running wirguard (192.168.3.233) in a debian container. In that network I have a windows pc (192.168.3.167) that i would like to connect to via RDP from my remote pc (192.168.3.251 wireguard interface). I can when a pcs are in the same local network sent pings from each to each other system.
However as soon as I connect the remote pc via wireguard the other hosts are not able to resolve (192.168.3.251).
This is my proxmox wireguard config:
[Interface]

Address = 192.168.3.250/24

SaveConfig = true

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.3.167 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.3.167 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEP
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i wg0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -s 192.168.3.167 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -s 192.168.3.167 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey =

[Peer]

PublicKey =
AllowedIPs = 192.168.3.251/32

This is my remote config:
[Interface]

PrivateKey =
Address = 192.168.3.251/32
MTU = 1420
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]

PublicKey =

AllowedIPs = 192.168.3.167/32
Endpoint = x.duckdns.org:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 21

This is the tcpdump on the proxmox;
19:09:16.635180 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 41345, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
192.168.3.251 > 192.168.3.167: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 29, length 40
19:09:16.635438 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.3.251 tell 192.168.3.233, length 28

Any idea why the remote adress is not resolved? Help would be very appreciated me and chatgpt a trying for a while.
I have tried a lot of different iptable configuations, differtent hosts etc. But it seems like nothing is working. I do not find people trying exactly the same to follow theit guides.

You have some serious misunderstanding on how networking / routing works. You can't just have a WG tunnel (mis)using some of your LAN subnet IPs and expect your other LAN hosts to be able to reach your WG clients. That only works with L2 VPN like tap mode OpenVPN, while WG works more or less the same way as tun mode OpenVPN. With that said usually you don't want to use an L2 VPN just because of that, but instead you either add routes on your LAN hosts for the WG subnet, or more conveniently, configure source NAT (IP masquerade) on the WG "server". Use a separate IP subnet for the WG.

If you have some serious need on having the WG client look like a (separate) host in your LAN, you might want to take a look at proxy ARP too.

I obviously have some serious misunderstandings otherwise I probably woulf habe figured our a solution.

okay I try to interprete your answers, i need to make the lan hosts see my wg client, which i can do by adding routes to the host, configure a source NAT or set up a ARP proxy that translates the adresses?

Using a seperate wireguard subnet like 10.0.0.x made things work, did not need any entries to the ip tables.
For RDP to work with a MS account I had to add the ip and PC-name to /etc/hosts off the remote pc.
